# Opencv mlp is not working with tag CvANN_MLP::UPDATE_WEIGHTS

Tags: c++, opencv, neural-network

I am new using Opencv and in particular multilayers perceptron (mlp). I want to train the network multiple time. Thus, I use the tag CvANN_MLP::UPDATE_WEIGHTS. since I dont want my inputs and outputs to be normalized, I use the tag CvANN_MLP::NO_INPUT_SCALE + CvANN_MLP::NO_OUTPUT_SCALE.
But the code crashes with the error: OpenCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (Some of new output training vector components run exceed the original range too much) in CvANN_MLP::calc_output_scale
code :

```
//creation of the multilayer perceptron
Mat layers = cv::Mat(3, 1, CV_32SC1);
layers.row(0) = Scalar(1);
layers.row(1) = Scalar(2);
layers.row(2) = Scalar(1);

CvANN_MLP mlp;
mlp.create(layers, CvANN_MLP::SIGMOID_SYM, 1, 1);

//the training inputs and outputs
Mat trainingData(2, 1, CV_32FC1);
Mat trainingClasses(2, 1, CV_32FC1);

trainingData.at<float>(Point(0, 0)) = 1;
trainingData.at<float>(Point(0, 1)) = -1;

trainingClasses.at<float>(Point(0, 0)) = 1;
trainingClasses.at<float>(Point(0, 1)) = -1;

//the training params
CvANN_MLP_TrainParams params;
CvTermCriteria criteria;
criteria.max_iter = 1;
criteria.epsilon = 0.00001f;
criteria.type = CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS;
params.train_method = CvANN_MLP_TrainParams::BACKPROP;
params.bp_dw_scale = 1.0f;
params.bp_moment_scale = 1.0f;
params.term_crit = criteria;

//seems like whe have to do that in order to initialize the weights
mlp.train(trainingData, trainingClasses, Mat(), Mat(), params, CvANN_MLP::NO_INPUT_SCALE + CvANN_MLP::NO_OUTPUT_SCALE);

for (int i(0); i < 10; i++)
{
    //this is the point where it crashes
    mlp.train(trainingData, trainingClasses, Mat(), Mat(), params, CvANN_MLP::UPDATE_WEIGHTS + CvANN_MLP::NO_INPUT_SCALE + CvANN_MLP::NO_OUTPUT_SCALE);

    for (int j(0); j < trainingData.rows; j++)
    {
        Mat input = trainingData.row(j);
        Mat output(1, 1, CV_32FC1);

        mlp.predict(input, output);

        cout << output.at<float>(0, 0) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution tot his? I know it was 2 years ago, but I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

using this method

Ptr<cv::ml::TrainData> train_data = cv::ml::TrainData::create(trainData, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, trainLabels);

Comment: Please explain how this answer relates to (and answers) the question. `trainData` and `trainLabels` are not defined (neither in the question nor in your answer), and it's not clear at all where in OP's code (if anywhere) this snippet should go, nor how this is solving OP's issue.